# Customize the aliases list in Locator Style Template

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I'm having problems in getting one of my aliases to work in my customized Locator:

I've adapted one of ESRI's Locator Style Templates to my needs. In doing so, I set a bunch of new aliases in the *Aliases* section inside *grammar*. Overall, it is working properly, but I'm having trouble in getting any alias with the sequence of characters **.º** to work, which is a common in portuguese abbreviations.

I transcribe bellow a part of my Locator Style Template defining aliases for the word *"primeiro"*:

```
<grammar>
<!-- (...) -->
     <section desc="Aliases">
          <alias_list name="StreetNameAliases">
               <!-- (...) -->
               <alias_def>
                    <alt>primeiro</alt>
                    <alt>1º</alt>
                    <alt>1.º</alt>
               </alias_def>
<!-- (...) -->
```

With this definition, the locator successfuly matches the input string *"rua 1º de maio"* to the address *"Rua Primeiro de Maio"* (100 matching score), but it gives no matching candidates for the input string *"rua 1.º de maio"*!!!

I already tried to substitute the **.** with the `&#46;` HTML code and several other workarounds and nothing worked.

Any thoughts on what's happening and how to correct it? HELP, these Locator Style Templates are a complete madness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ESRI's geocoding engine constructing the locator was replacing the periods in the input template with spaces, so the solution was to replace all the period symbols in the aliases definition with spaces.

So, the example above became:

```
<grammar>
<!-- (...) -->
     <section desc="Aliases">
          <alias_list name="StreetNameAliases">
               <!-- (...) -->
               <alias_def>
                    <alt>primeiro</alt>
                    <alt>1º</alt>
                    <alt>1 º</alt>
               </alias_def>
<!-- (...) -->
```

Comment: Thanks to Shana Britt (https://community.esri.com/message/743258-customize-the-aliases-list-in-locator-style-template) on helping with this.